# SQL manipulation of table (aggregate and grouping)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I would like to make a daily query (using bigquery) to compare the sums for different metrics between yesterday and today. sample dataset look like this: 
[image]

assuming today is 23 Dec 2019, the query will aggregate different metrics (revenue, cost, profit) for different customer for 23 Dec (today) and 22 Dec (yesterday), if sum(yesterday)/sum(today) is not within the threshold of 0.5-1.5, then it will be labelled as anomalous

the query will be made daily and new result will simply be appended. ideally the final table would look like this:

[image]
My main concern is that I am able to do this for one metric only (i.e revenue), but not sure how to apply to all metrics (and also make the query more efficient). this is the code i have written

```
SELECT cust_id,

SUM(CASE WHEN date = DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL -1 DAY) 
         THEN revenue
    END) AS sum(yesterday),

SUM(CASE WHEN date = DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 0 DAY)
         THEN revenue
    END) AS sum(today),

SUM(CASE WHEN date = DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL -1 DAY) 
         THEN revenue
    END) / SUM(CASE WHEN date = DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 0 DAY)
         THEN revenue
    END) as ratio,

FROM `dataset`
GROUP BY cust_id
```

and the code gives me:
 [image]

Apologies in advance for the lack of clarity in the question, as I am new to this and not sure how to phrase this question more accurately

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to put the source data in an Excel pivot table. (move the Values group to the rows to get the desired view.).

if you want to stick to SQL however, you need to unpivot the rows first, by putting each measure in a separate row and then group the intermediate results, like this:

```
WITH unpivoted AS
(
    SELECT
        date
      , 'revenue'       AS metrics
      , SUM( revenue )  AS amount
      , cust_id
    FROM
        `dataset`
    GROUP
    BY
        date
      , cust_id

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        date
      , 'cost'          AS metrics
      , SUM( cost )     AS amount
      , cust_id
    FROM
        `dataset`
    GROUP
    BY
        date
      , cust_id
    -- add more desired metrics
)
SELECT
    date as date_generated
  , cust_id
  , metrics
  , SUM( CASE WHEN date = DATE_ADD( CURRENT_DATE() , INTERVAL  0 DAY ) THEN amount END ) AS today
  , SUM( CASE WHEN date = DATE_ADD( CURRENT_DATE() , INTERVAL -1 DAY ) THEN amount END ) AS yesterday
    ...

FROM
    unpivoted
WHERE
    date >= DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL -1 DAY ) 
AND date <= DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL  0 DAY ) 

GROUP
BY
    date, cust_id, metrics
```

Answer (score 0):

You can summarize the data and then use `lag()` or a `join` to bring in the previous days data:

```
with t as (
      select cust_id, date,
             sum(revenue) as revenue,
             sum(cost) as cost,
             sum(profit) as profit
      from dataset
      where date >= date_add(current_date, interval -1 day)
      group by cust_id, date
     )
select t.cust_id,
       today, yesterday
from t today left join
     t yesterday
     on yesterday.cust_id = today.cust_id and
        yesterday.date = date_add(current_date, interval -1 day)
where today.date = current_date;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can unpivot the columns first and then group the results. After that, you might need to use LAG() to show data from one day and the previous one in the same row.

```
WITH unpivoted AS
(
  SELECT
    date,
    'revenue' AS metrics,
    SUM( revenue ) AS amount,
    cust_id
  FROM
    `dataset`
  GROUP BY
    date, metrics, cust_id

UNION ALL

  SELECT
    date,
    'cost' AS metrics,
    SUM( cost ) AS amount,
    cust_id
  FROM
    `dataset`
  GROUP BY
    date, metrics, cust_id

UNION ALL

  SELECT
    date,
    'profit' AS metrics,
    SUM( profit ) AS amount,
    cust_id
  FROM
    `dataset`
  GROUP BY
    date, metrics, cust_id
)

SELECT
  date as date_generated,
  metrics,
  cust_id,
  LAG(SUM( amount )) OVER (PARTITION BY cust_id, metrics ORDER BY date) yesterday,
  SUM( amount ) AS today,
  LAG(SUM( amount )) OVER (PARTITION BY cust_id, metrics ORDER BY date) / SUM(amount) as ratio,
  CASE WHEN LAG(SUM( amount )) OVER (PARTITION BY cust_id, metrics ORDER BY date) / SUM(amount)<0.5 then 'TRUE' 
      WHEN LAG(SUM( amount )) OVER (PARTITION BY cust_id, metrics ORDER BY date) / SUM(amount)>1.5 then 'TRUE'
      WHEN LAG(SUM( amount )) OVER (PARTITION BY cust_id, metrics ORDER BY date) / SUM(amount) is NULL then 'TRUE'
      ELSE 'FALSE'
  END as anomalous

FROM
  unpivoted

WHERE date >= DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL -1 DAY ) AND date <= DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL  0 DAY )    

GROUP BY 
  date_generated, cust_id, metrics

ORDER BY 
  date_generated, metrics, cust_id
```

Note that my solution is only limited to current day and previous day (today and yesterday) when using the WHERE clause, so this could be used to aggregate metrics from more than two days.